# javaScript function, making code dry

Tags: javascript

I have 15 elements in a row with the same class for example `class="element"` i want to make a jQuery each loop to add them classes like left-el and right-el.
Now i have a code like this:

```
jQuery('.element').eq(0).addClass('left-el');
jQuery('.element').eq(1).addClass('right-el');
jQuery('.element').eq(2).addClass('left-el');
jQuery('.element').eq(3).addClass('right-el');
```

up to 15. Wanna make dry but dont know how. Maybe that's a stupid question but i cant fix for a hours. Tried something like this:

```
jQuery('.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle').each(function(i, item){

    var left = 'ui-slider-handle-left';
    var right = 'ui-slider-handle-right';

    jQuery('.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle').eq(i).addClass(i == 0 ? left : right+i);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery has [`:odd`](https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) and `:even` selectors that allow code such as yours to be done like this:

```
jQuery('.element:even').addClass('left-el');
jQuery('.element:odd').addClass('right-el');  // Or the other way around
```

Comment: Working great! Thanks, but also want to see a loop way;)

Comment: I originally thought about giving you a loop way, but it is inefficient and I didn't want you to see it :D

Comment: @pwnz22 as a loop: `jQuery('.element').each(function(i){ 
 $(this).addClass(i&1? 'right-el': 'left-el');
});`, but as Brian said, his answer should be prefered.

Answer (score 1):

do this way,

```
$(".element:even").addClass('left-el');
$(".element:odd").addClass('right-el');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('.element').each(function(i){
var left = 'ui-slider-handle-left',
    right = 'ui-slider-handle-right';

   if (i%2 === 0) {
      $(this).addClass(left);
   } else {
      $(this).addClass(right);
   }
});
```